# Solving the recurrence $a_{n+2} = 3a_{n+1} - 2a_n, a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3$ using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Solve the following recurrence using generating functions: $a_{n+2} = 3a_{n+1} - 2a_n, a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3$.

**My partial solution:**

We can rewrite $a_{n+2} = 3a_{n+1} - 2a_n$, as $a_{n+2} - 3a_{n+1} + 2a_n = 0$, and we let $A(z) = \sum a_n z^n$. The goal is to compute $A(z)$ as this can be done as follows: $$A(z) - a_0 - a_1z - 3z(A(z) - a_0) + 2z^2A(z) = 0$$
$$(1-3z+2z^2)A(z) = a_0 + a_1z -3a_0z$$
$$A(z) = \frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3a_0)z}{1-3z+2z^2}$$
$$\quad \quad = \frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3a_0)z}{(1-z)(1-2z)}$$
$$\quad \quad = \frac{C}{(1-z)}+\frac{D}{(1-2z)}$$

And, I don't know how to continue, I cannot figure out the remaining. I'm pretty sure it is obvious, but I just cannot see it. If someone can help me I would be glad.

Comment: This is correct. Stop guessing and go on.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with generating functions, but it seems you should be able to figure out the power series for $1/(1-z)$ and $1/(1-2z)$, figure out the constants $C$ and $D$, and then you have $A(z)$ as a linear combination of two other series, so combine them term by term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints.

To find $C$ and $D$, use that $a_0 = A(0)$ and $a_1 = A'(0)$. Two equations in two unknowns..

Once the above is done, use the following identity to get the formula for each $a_n$.
$${1  \over 1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ....$$

Comment: Since that's the simplest power series there is, I don't think it should be given out on homework problems. It's easy to compute.

Comment: I think students know how to use google.

Comment: Some of us just want hints, and only look for explicit results after failing to be able to work it out. Yes they can find this online, but providing it takes away that choice.

Comment: Go away, you're annoying. People have different styles of answering.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{C}{1-z}+\frac{D}{1-2z} &= \frac{C(1-2z)}{(1-z)(1-2z)} + \frac{(1-z)D}{(1-z)(1-2z)} \\\\ &= \frac{(C+D)+(-2C-D)z}{(1-z)(1-2z)} \\\\ &= \frac{(a_0)+(a_1-3a_0)z}{(1-z)(1-2z)}
\end{align}

You now have 2 linear equations and easily solve for $C$ and $D$ in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$.

What is the power series for $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$?  It's a simple one, try [long hand division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), and you'll see the coefficient pattern after a few terms.  Note that $\dfrac{1}{1-2z}$ is just $\dfrac{1}{1-y}$ with $y=2z$.

Let $\displaystyle F(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n z^n$ be that power series.

Then $\displaystyle A(z) = CF(z)+DF(2z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (C+D2^n)f_n z^n$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick for partial fractions: Say yu have:
$$
\frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3 a_0) z}{(1 - z) (1 - 2 z)} = \frac{A}{1 - z} + \frac{B}{1 - 2 z}
$$

This is supposed to be an identity, so for instance:

$\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \to 1/2} \left(
                   (1 - 2 z) 
                      \cdot \frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3 a_0) z}{(1 - z) (1 - 2 z)}
                 \right)
  &= \lim_{z \to 1/2} \left(
                        (1 - 2 z) 
                          \cdot \frac{A}{1 - z}
                      \right)
       + \lim_{z \to 1/2} \left(
                            (1 - 2 z) 
                               \cdot \frac{B}{1 - 2 z}
                          \right) \\
\left. \frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3 a_0) z}{(1 - z)} \right|_{z = 1/2}
   &= 0 + B \\
\frac{a_0 + (a_1 - 3 a_0) \cdot 1/2}{1/2}
   &= B
\end{align*}$

This simplifies to $B = a_1 - a_0$.

The same works for $A$.